# I want to catch a generic exception as my Api can crash due to many reason. So I cannot throw for each and every step. below is the sample code

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
void fun(int x ,int y ,int* arr)
{
    int z = x/y; //operation 1
    int s = arr[z]; // operation 2
    //... many more operation
}

int main()
{ 
try
{
    fun();
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    cout<<e.what();
}
    return 0;
}
```

My operation 1 can crash because of divide 0 if y is 0. my index can be out of range and many more operation can cause different different issue. So how can I catch them without throwing exception.

Because in my real time situation my program can crash due to any reason and I cannot throw/catch for each and every step .
My program shouldn't crash instead I should be able to catch the exception and log it.

e.g. the fun() api can crash due to many operation and I want it should not terminate my program.

Basically I am looking for an generic approach to catch the exception without using throw keyword.

Comment: You don't need `throw` to catch an exception. You use `throw` to throw an exception. Do you mean: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv Dividing by zero causes a floating-point exception but _"The floating-point exceptions are not related to the C++ exceptions."_

Comment: Dividing by zero does not throw an exception.

Comment: C++ knows only about exceptions that are thrown via the `throw` statement. It has no concept of exceptions that are thrown by the OS itself. Things like access violations, *divide by zero errors*, etc are simply not catchable by a C++ `try...catch` block (unless you happen to be using a 3rd party C++ library that intercepts such OS errors and translates them into C++ exceptions). Otherwise, look into platform-specific solutions, such as [Structured Exception Handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019) ( `__try...__except`) on Windows.